# Client side routing vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, express

I'm attempting to make a very simple client router.  My server is bare bones:

```
const http = require('http')
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()

// Set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

// Catch all 'get' requests, and respond with public/index.html
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.url)
  if (req.url.indexOf('/api/') === -1) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'))
  } else {
    return next()
  }
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on port " + port)
  if (process.send) {
    process.send({ event:'online', url:'http://localhost:' + port})
  }
})

module.exports = app;
```

My `index.html` is also very thin:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My App</title>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="my-app">My App</div>
  <script src="router.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My `router.js` file that runs client side:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  if (window.location.pathname === '/register') {
    const myApp = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
    const layout = document.createElement('script')
    layout.src = 'javascripts/layout.js'
    myApp.appendChild(layout)
  } else if (window.location.pathname === '/register/about') {
    console.log("In about page")
  }
})
```

`layout.js` (also client side):

```
const layout = `
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="header clearfix">
        <nav style="padding-top: 10px">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-left">
            <li role="presentation">
              <a href="/"><h3>My App</h3></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
            <li role="presentation"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
`;

document.getElementById('my-app').innerHTML = layout;
```

When I attempt to load `http://localhost:3000/register`, I get "My App" in the body, which I expect since I'm sending `index.html` from the server.  But I also get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`.  I believe it's because HTML is being returned, rather than JS.

**Is my index.html file setup correctly as an entry point to the app?**

Comment: This is kind of old and you may have figured it out already, but your opening script tag in index.html is missing '>'.

Comment: nope... the `src`,`integrity` and `crossorigin` are script attributes